# Attempting to get JSON from session multiple times for X time with one command

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to start this off by saying I'm very new to Python/Coding in general and have mostly been winging it by reading resources/forums online.

I'm trying to make a repeat cog for my Discord bot. I'm almost done with it but I'm stuck on this one issue and do not know enough about how aiohttp works to truly figure it out.

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import asyncio
import random
import aiohttp

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

class auto(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=self.bot.loop)

    @bot.command(pass_context=True)
    async def auto(self, ctx):
        timeout = 1*5
        async with self.session.get("https://nekos.life/api/v2/img/neko") as resp:
            messages = await resp.json()
        while True:
            embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.blue())
            embed.set_image(url=messages['url'])
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            await asyncio.sleep(timeout)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(auto(bot))
```

The expected result from this is that it will post a different embedded image every five seconds.

The actual result is that it does post the image every five seconds, but it's the same image. It never changes. Unless you rerun the command.

I know the issue is likely that it's pulling from the API once and then sending the image, then it pauses there and just keeps running the sending every five seconds. I just don't know a way to fix it to where it will loop back around.

Some info about the URL that I'm using: Each time you reload the page it will give a new link. If you open the link that is showing you can see it for yourself. It will give you the JSON data and 'url' points to the given link.

Comment: So I'm not sure what that `async with self.session.get()` is supposed to do, but the problem here is that in your main while loop, your accessing the same the key of that dictionary with `messages['url']`, so you'll get the same result so long as the value at that key isn't changing.

Comment: Sorry I meant to include some info about the URL in the original post. Each time that website refereshes the 'url' entry gets a new link. It's a bit hard to explain but if you open it you will see the JSON data and each time you refresh the 'URL' changes.

Comment: Right, so then I think the issue here is that your json isn't being updated. I know `async` is new in python but I don't have any experience with it. Instead, for my sake, could you move the GET request and `messages = await resp.json()` into your while loop? If it still fails after that, actually print the json inside of `messages` and make sure this is indeed actually updating.

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so much! That was way more simple than i was making it out to be. :/

For your sanity, the first option is what worked. Moving the ``async`` into the while loop.